# Difference between this and scope in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angularjs.
What is the difference if You assign function to $scope or this keywords in the controller?
Thank You.

Example (scope):

```
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testFunc = function () {
    };
}]);
```

Example (this)

```
.controller('TestCtrl', [function () {
    var app = this;
    app.testFunc = function () {
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$scope` is a core concept of angular framework and dual data-binding functionnalities. Its for example, designed to share its content with :

- templates
- directives
- etc

In a template for example, you'll need to bind a function to the `scope` to access it. You'll not be able to call a function binded on `this` directly.

---

**Edit:** Thank to [BKM post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807947/1112003) that pointed out that this behavior is possible with the "controller as" syntax which binds your template directly to the controller. But it's up to you to decide if you want to let access all objects/variables of your controller in your template instead of having a dedicated `viewModel` (`scope`). For pros and cons, see : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/84selECbp1I

---

It's an important concept of angular that you need to understand.

See :

- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope for an introduction
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes for more technical information about scopes

`this` keywork refers only the the javascript `object` refering to your `controller`, nothing more.

Answer (score 8):

What Bixi said was wrong. It isn't necessary to have a function bind to the scope inorder to access it.

In the newest version of `Angular JS` i.e, `1.2` they have introduces a new keyword `controllerAs` to make it possible not to have scope inside a controller.

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
    {{test.value}}
</div>
```

And in your controller

```
app.controller('testCtrl ', function () {
   this.value = 'Hello World';
});
```

See the above controller is generated with out injecting `$scope` in it.

[Here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax) is a good video tutorial explaining this

Comment: @BKM that was exactly the tutorial I have watched and saw this concept so I needed clarification for it.
Thank You for Your answers guys, cheers! ;)