# Difference between "this" and "$scope" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I read AngularJS documentation and also this question [this vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers).I get a part of my required answer here [Difference between this and scope in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806681/difference-between-this-and-scope-in-the-controller) as well. I have a simple confusion regarding "this" and "$scope" in my code, I followed [CodeSchool Tutorial suggested by Official AngularJS Page](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js), and I wrote this code

Controller (Using 'this' as I practiced on Code School ):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myApp.controller('TestController', function () {
    this.name = 'Yawar Khan';
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <h1> Hello {{name}} to AngularJS ! </h1> 
  </div>

</body>
```

And it is not evaluating the AgularJS expression and not outputting the value of name.

But if I use $Scope in my controller like

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Yawar Khan';
}]);
```

Output is correct i.e. AgularJS expression {{name}} is evaluated as name value given in controller.

can anyone explain it to me that why everything worked perfectly on Code School tutorials with only 'this' ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806681/difference-between-this-and-scope-in-the-controller try to have a look here!

Comment: Okay thanks, But can anyone explain it to me that why everything worked perfectly on Code School tutorials with only  'this' ?

Comment: We would have to actually see the tutorial to tell you that. It's likely using the controllerAs syntax (which is mentioned and demonstrated in the duplicate question)

Comment: @kevin Thanks, I got the point. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22807947/2860391 Is the answer to my main question