# not able to bind data from controller to view. No error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am learning angular and trying to bind data from model to view. But its not throwing any error. Can you help me.

```
<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="emp"> 
 Hello {{emp.name}}, I am happy that you are getting a salary of{{emp.salary}}.
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('emp', function(){
 this.name = "John";
 this.salary = 4500;
});
```

Please find [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/duhfgbb9/)

Comment: Another interesting answer here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `ng-controller="emp"` to `ng-controller="emp as emp"`

```
<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="emp as emp"> 
     Hello {{emp.name}}, I am happy that you are getting a salary of{{emp.salary}}.
    </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vedp/duhfgbb9/1/

Comment: @shams.kool {{name}}  will not work as `name` is not $scope variable.

Comment: @Ved Yes it worked. Thanks But can you explain why? It is something related to angular version I am using.

Comment: @Megh please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806681/difference-between-this-and-scope-in-the-controller

or just search it google there are lot of related answers.

Comment: @Megh it is not releated to Angular version. with Controller As syntax   work with controllers as classes.Check this answe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`controller as syntax`** here,

change to  `ng-controller="emp as emp"`

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('emp', function(){
 this.name = "John";
 this.salary = 4500;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ="myApp" ng-controller="emp as emp"> 
 Hello {{emp.name}}, I am happy that you are getting a salary of{{emp.salary}}.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$scope`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('emp', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.empData = {
    name: "John",
    salary: 4500
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="emp">
  Hello {{empData.name}}, I am happy that you are getting a salary of{{empData.salary}}.
</div>
```